# how to combine firstname and lastname in SQL and search with LIKE

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I would like to combine `FirstName` and `LastName` into one column called `'FULL NAME'` and search with LIKE in SQL.

Example 1:

> FirstName : Milan
>   LastName: Patel
>
> FullName: Milan Patel

Search with: `Like '%SomeText%'`

Example 2:

> Title: " Meetings: A practical alternative to work."

Search: I would like to search the entire word within the give string. ex: work should return the above title.

Here is what I have so far.

```
SELECT 
    CE.Title, CC.FirstName + ' ' + CC.LastName AS FullName
FROM 
    EntryTable CE
JOIN 
    UserTable CC ON CE.EntryId = CC.USerId
WHERE 
    CC.FirstName LIKE 'n%'
```

## EDIT

I am getting it there slowly. search is working fine with this query.

```
    SELECT 
     CE.Title 
    FROM 
     EntryTable CE
    JOIN 
     UserTable CC
    ON 
     CE.EntryId = CC.USerId
    WHERE 
     CC.FirstName  + ' ' + CC.LastName LIKE 's%'
```

BUT it only search for name starting with `'s'`, i would like to search name starting, ending, contains conditions as well. how can i go about that. please help

Comment: Why don't you create a computed column that holds the *full name* in the first place? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx  ....you then have it at all times and don't need to mangle it together in queries with `+`

Comment: _"here is what i have got so far"_ - and what does that do?

Comment: Searck Like `'%sometext%'` and `'sometext%'` are differrent things

Comment: ***WHAT*** database system? The string manipulation capabilities vary widely between vendors - SQL is just the query language, not a product - so that really doesn't tell us what system you're using....

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` with concatenated column values as below

```
WHERE 
  CC.FirstName + ' ' + CC.LastName LIKE 's%'
```

> BUT it only search for name starting with 's', i would like to search
>   name starting, ending, contains conditions as well. how can i go about
>   that. please help

Then you have to use `%` before and after search string like below

```
WHERE 
  CC.FirstName + ' ' + CC.LastName LIKE '%s%'
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use concat

```
   SELECT CE.Title, concat(CC.FirstName , ' ' , CC.LastName) AS FullName
   FROM EntryTable CE
  JOIN UserTable CC
  ON CE.EntryId = CC.USerId
  WHERE 
  concat(CC.FirstName , ' ' , CC.LastName) LIKE 'n%'
  OR  CC.FirstName LIKE 'n%' OR  CC.FirstName LIKE '%n'
  OR  CC.LastName LIKE 'n%'  OR CC.LastName LIKE '%n'
                        ^^--// (1).   ^^--// (2)
```

(1) to find lastname in first of the string you search .

(2) to find lastname in the end of the string you search.

(3)to find last name in middle of string do this '%n%'

Comment: OP wants to search the `FullName` col

Comment: i like this answer. BUT i am confuse as to how would i search for both like fullname as well as words matching in title.

Comment: you can do many OR statment to search by words i edited my answer. added two or to search by firstname and last name also

Answer (score 5):

you can't use the `ALIAS` on the `WHERE` clause because in the SQL Order of Operation, the `WHERE` clause is executed before the `SELECT` clause.

better use the complete concatenation is the `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE CC.FirstName + ' ' + CC.LastName LIKE 'n%'
```

if you don't want to use that, wrap your query in a subquery so you can use the `ALIAS`,

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT CE.Title, CC.FirstName + ' ' + CC.LastName AS FullName
   FROM   EntryTable CE JOIN UserTable CC
          ON CE.EntryId = CC.USerId
) sub
WHERE sub.FullName LIKE 'n%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Where CONCAT(CC.FirstName, ' ', CC.LastName) Like "%n%"

Answer (score 2):

Combine them in the WHERE clause as well, with two % signs.

Comment: Okay where's the difference between an answer and a comment?

Comment: @Dado Jerry, yes, huge difference. I'd really like to understand, as I strongly believe that short sentence answers the question. Just like the piece of code by Damith that got upvoted. My answer just requires some understanding...

Comment: This isn't a bad answer, and doesn't look like a comment too. The other answers are worse than this one, as they dump code without explanation or even don't answer the question at all.

Comment: Actually this is the only one that addresses the concern, good if you could expand it a bit more

Comment: I know I'm not really supposed to write thank-you-notes, but thanks to CodeCaster and V4Vendetta. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT some_column_name FROM some_table where firstname + ' ' + lastname LIKE 'some_value'
```

no `FullName` column needed.